# My frequency response curve won't actually display, am I missing something simple?

Tags: function, matplotlib, plot, frequency

I am supposed to plot a frequency response curve with V on the y axis and Hz in log scale along the x, like the following picture:
[format for frequency response curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNdm9.png)

I have the function laid out and for some reason my code won't display the function when I run it, it shows a blank plot, what am I doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m

c=3.183e-6
for x in (1,100000):
    hz=x
    w=x*2*m.pi
    mag=1/m.sqrt(1+(50*c*w)**2)

plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(hz,mag)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `hz` and `mag` are float values overwritten every time in the for loop. So when you plot it, you are only plotting one single point. What you need to do is use a list and append every value

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m

c=3.183e-6

hz_list = list()
mag_list = list()

for x in (1,100000):
    hz_list.append(x)
    w=x*2*m.pi
    mag_list.append(1/m.sqrt(1+(50*c*w)**2))

#plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(hz_list, mag_list)
```

However, a better way to do this would be using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

hz_list = np.arange(1, 100000)
w = hz_list * 2 * np.pi
mag_list = 1 / np.sqrt(1 + (50 * c * w)**2)

plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(hz_list, mag_list)
```